# RXTX Java Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, rxtx

I have a problem with the RXTX library where I get this message error. I have looked at a lot of websites and forms and tried all of them but there is not an answer to my problem:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib: dlopen(/Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib: dlopen(/Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1858)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
    at javaduino.javaduinoframe.inicializarConexion(javaduinoframe.java:96)
    at javaduino.javaduinoframe.<init>(javaduinoframe.java:80)
    at javaduino.javaduinoframe$1.run(javaduinoframe.java:33)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to my problem the next day. I posted the question here: [Installing RXTX on Mac OS Mountain Lion](http://blog.brianhemeryck.me/installing-rxtx-on-mac-os-mountain-lion/).

The problem was that the file that goes into the `/Library/java/extension` directory was not updated. The website URL above has everything you need.

> 1. Go to http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download and download the binary version 2.1.7.
> 2. Unzip the folder and place the unzipped folder on your desktop.
> 3. Open the folder and navigate to the Mac_OS_X folder.
> 4. Delete the librxtxSerial.jnilib file (I found that this file is using Java 5, and with Mountain Lion I was using Java 6).
> 5. Go to Robert Harder’s blog and download his version of the librxtxSerial.jnilib file. Direct link here. Just want to say thank
>      you to Robert for his blog post – it saved me big time. What he has
>      done is compiled a Java 6 friendly version of librxtxSerial.jnilib.
> 6. Save this new librxtxSerial.jnilib file in the Mac_OS_X folder of the RXTX folder you have on your desktop from step 2.
> 7. Open Terminal and type the following:
>
>    cd /rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2/
>
>    sudo cp RXTXcomm.jar /Library/Java/Extensions
>
>    sudo cp Mac_OS_X/librxtxSerial.jnilib /Library/Java/Extensions

Answer (score 0):

STEP BY STEP tutorial. If you follow me from step 1 to step 16, then you will make it, I've used too much screen shots in this tutorial, cause I don't want to leave you in the middle of nowhere! Attention to the bold texts. Good luck!

1- Make sure you have **downloaded Java SE.6** from the link below and **installed it**:

[Download Java for OS X 2015-001](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US)

2- **Create a java project** in Eclipse, in the same window select **Use a specific JRE** then click on **configure JREs** like picture below:

[image]

3- Now select **Add**

[image]

4- Select **Standard VM** and click **next**, now click on the **Directory** in the opened window. Go to the your **HDD/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home** and **click open** like picture below:

[image]

5- Now you should see JRE system libraries like this:

[image: JRE Libraries]

6- Change JRE name to: Java SE.6 (it is not necessary but its better than to give it Home name), **now click finish**. like picture below:

[image]

7- In the new windows select Java SE.6, and **click OK**, like picture below:

[image]

8- Now select **Java SE.6** and **click finish**, like this picture:

[image]

9- Create a folder by right click on your project, select **new**, select **folder** name it "lib" or whatever you want.

[image]

10- Download **RXTXcomm.jar** from this link: [RXTXcomm.jar for Mac](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Phy23xsQC-a3pKbnRkN193a1E/view?usp=sharing) then **drag and drop it** into the folder "lib" which you created it in **step 9** and select **copy files**.

11- Now **Right click** on the RXTXcomm.jar and select **Build Path**, then select **Add to Build Path**.

12- Now **right click on your project**, then choose **Properties**, select **Java Build Path**, click on the **Libraries**, look at this picture:

[image]

**Don't give up, you're almost there :)**

13- Click on the little arrow of RXTXcomm.jar and expand it, Select **Native library location** and click on the edit or just double click, like picture below:

[image]

14- In the open window, select **Workspace** and select your **project** which you've made it for this tutorial and click **ok**.

15- Now download this file, [librxtxSerial.jnilib](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Phy23xsQC-ck1tNzNENU5WbEU/view?usp=sharing)

16- Copy and paste both **RXTXcomm.jar** and **librxtxSerial.jnilib** into this folder: HDD/Library/Java/Extensions (you need to enter your computer password).Look at this picture:

[image]

**Welldone! You made it :)**